# Cannot add custom domain to my current app

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect custom domain to my current project the issue is there is no place to add such domain ,
And why does goodie Claud generate 2 links (domains) for the same app makes no logic.[image]

Comment: Please update more details of any specific error you get, which document you are referring to and your observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually set up a custom domain completely in the Firebase console. To do so:

1. If you haven't set up Firebase Hosting for your project, open the
   Hosting page of the Firebase console, click Get Started, and click
   through the setup instructions.
2. Open the Dynamic Links page of the Firebase console.
3. If you haven't used Dynamic Links before, click Get Started.
   Otherwise, click Add URL prefix from the drop-down menu.
4. Then, complete the setup wizard, specifying the domain and path
   prefix you want to use when prompted.

Please follow this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) to set up the custom domains and further information.

Comment: I believe there is a bug in the console acting wieard